# Look for multiple values in a cell array at the same time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have `CellArray1` with 50 unique strings and `CellArray2` with 2000 unique strings (50 of which are the same as the ones in `CellArray1`).  Is there a way to find the positions of all 50 unique strings from the first cell array in the second cell array without using loops?

Comment: Does the result need to be sorted - in other words, if the first array is {'A','B','C'} and the second is Z...A, would you expect the answer to be [26,25,24] or is [24,25,26] acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the following code demonstrates this:

```
cellArray1 = {'hello', 'world'};
cellArray2 = {'good', 'morning', 'world'};
overlap = find(ismember(cellArray2, cellArray1)};
```

This will return the value `3` in `overlap` since `cellArray2{3}` appears in `cellArray1`.

**UPDATE**

The above code returns the indices, but not in the order of the original. If you need the original order, you can do the following

```
overlap = cellfun(@(x)find(ismember(cellArray2, x)), cellArray1, 'uniformOutput', false);
overlapSorted = cell2mat(overlap);
```

It could be argued that `cellfun` actually has an implicit loop in it (but then all vector operations have implicit loops, really); but one of these constructions will do what you asked for. If you don't need it sorted, the first will be significantly faster, I imagine.